# How do I set a maximum duration for notes in command line TiMidity synthesis?

Tags: midi, synthesizer

I'm using the following command to synthesize MIDIs:

```
timidity -A120 -a in.mid Ow2 -o out.wav
```

However, some of the notes drag on for longer than I'd like and leave a metallic sound. I'd like to add an option to this command